# mod rewrite not working with laravel and bitNami

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp, laravel, bitnami

http.conf has mod rewrite uncommented

so no custom routes are working someone in #laravel mentioned it would be because mod rewrite isn't working here is my setup:

laravel.conf has the following code:

```
Alias /laravel/ "C:\BitNami/frameworks/laravel/public/"
Alias /laravel "C:\BitNami/frameworks/laravel/public"

<Directory "C:\BitNami/frameworks/laravel/public">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride None
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

If I uncomment these lines:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^/$ /laravel/ [PT]
```

then the main route will map to

```
http://localhost/
```

rather than

```
http://localhost/laravel
```

which is preferable but secondary to the main problem

.htaccess inside the public folder has this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /laravel
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

here is my test code inside routes.php:

```
Route::get('test',function(){
return 'test worked';
});
```

which should resolve with

```
http://localhost/laravel/test
```

but instead I get a 404 error

Comment: Have same problem and no idea how to fix it under Windows...

Answer (score 0):

RewriteBase and RewriteEngine are defined twice. Make your .htaccess file look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If possible, it would be best to use Apache virtual hosts instead.

Comment: I had the same idea, and deleted those lines before this post but I had the same problem, I've copied and pasted your answer into .htaccess in the public folder of laravel but alas I still have the same problems as described in original post

Comment: How would I go about adding a Apache virtual host?

Comment: I never used BitNami, just noticed the duplication in the .htaccess file. When I was running Windows, I used [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). You would have to edit the httpd-vhosts.conf file and add the new site information. There is usually an example. Then in your Windows hosts file (c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) add 
`127.0.0.1 example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file should look like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```